# Configure AdBlock Plus to only block video ads

Tags: browser-addons, adblock

Ive recently installed AdBlock Plus in my browser, I've noticed now that the ads are gone, I kind of miss them, particularly the remarketing ones, which I find quite useful.

I was searching to see if there is a configuration option where you can set it to just block video ads (as this was the main reason i installed it) whilst leaving normal display ads in place, but couldn't find anything, does any one know if this is possible?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to unsubscribe from all the filter lists and add the following custom rule:

```
||ytimg.com^*/swfbin/*ad3
```

Source:
https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=19283

Comment: this does not seem to work now … does anyone have a new rule?